# Regex - no consecutive special chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex with these requirements:

- there mustn't be any consecutive characters except from letters and numbers

Example: I'm #1! I feel greaaaat! (OK), I''m kinda .{}. sad (NOT OK)

- there mustn't be more than 4 characters except from letters and numbers

Example: a.a,aaa (OK), a.a,a[]a/ (NOT OK)

I've written this Regex so far, but it seems to be not working properly.

`` /^(?!.*?[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~]{2})[A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~].*$/ ``

Can you suggest any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?!.*[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{2})[A-Za-z0-9 ]*(?:[!-\/:-@[-`{-~][A-Za-z0-9 ]*){0,4}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlJBSJ/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `` (?!.*[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{2}) `` - no two consecutive ASCII punctuation after any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[A-Za-z0-9 ]*` - zero or more letters, digits or spaces
- `` (?:[!-\/:-@[-`{-~][A-Za-z0-9 ]*){0,4} `` - zero to four occurrences of

  - `` [!-\/:-@[-`{-~] `` - a single ASCII punctuation char
  - `[A-Za-z0-9 ]*` - zero or more letters, digits or spaces
- `$` - end of string.